# php redirect fails and does not do anything

Tags: php, header

i have just a simple php file with this line of code.

```
  <?php header("Location: MyBooks.php", true); exit();?>
```

Form 1 submits form to this simple php file and this file supposed to redirects to MyBooks.php within the same directory.

i just do not get it, why it does not redirects ?

there's no errors reported.

Comment: why don't you let form submit to MyBooks.php directly?

Comment: @ajreal: Possibly to implement the [PRG pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)?

Comment: yeah. i want to prevent re-submit.

Comment: @ajreal: We 'll have to disagree there. Personally I believe it is *required* that a well-written web app does this. And I 'm not alone.

Comment: @Melvin @Jon -- if you want to prevent re-submit, IMHO ... i would think submit to MyBooks.php directly ... and redirect after you have done all the processing at MyBooks.php instead of redirect first, process later.

Comment: Maybe it's only a problem of the case sensitive filename? Check if the filename is exactly written as "MyBooks.php".

Comment: @ajreal: It seems to me that `MyBooks.php` is what you should go to *after* processing. If you do a redirect such as in the example you will lose all the POST parameters, so I don't think that `MyBooks.php` does any processing (it gets no input, what would it process?). It's probably displaying a list of the books.

Comment: @Jon -- relook at what Melvin posted, `Form 1 submits form to this simple php file and this file supposed to redirects to MyBooks.php`, @Melvin -- might has to clarify this , as you mention `simple` ... which assuming it just do the redirect

Comment: What browser are you using? I know Safari has problem with redirecting when when there was no full URI specified in `Location` header. Chrome may also be affected. Try using `Location: http://localhost/MyBooks.php`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like an issue in server you are running: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/db37d2ea-65ef-40ad-8a25-62a846a5d00d/php-headers-and-redirect

So you have to manually specify response code to **302** before sending location header:

```
header('HTTP/1.0 302 Found');
header('Location: http://localhost/MyBooks.php');
exit;
```

And remember to use absolute URL in `Location`.

Comment: my solution was to remain the code but instead of running from MS Web Dev server, i run from apache server. Solves the compatibility problem.

Comment: You should use 303 on a POST-activated response.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible that you have already sent some output through your script (which could be just whitespace), in which case you cannot send headers anymore.

Test it with this code:

```
if (headers_sent()) {
    die("Error: headers already sent!");
}
else {
    header("Location: MyBooks.php", true);
    exit();
}
```

If this prints an error, then you need to make sure that there's no output at all going out before the `header` call. Check that:

- You do not `echo` anything at all (or otherwise output any HTML) before the `header` call
- There is absolutely no whitespace before the `<?php` start tag or the `?>` end tag (if present) in your PHP scripts

**Update: How to check HTTP headers using Chrome**

[image: How to check HTTP headers using Chrome]

1. Select the Network tab
2. Choose Documents from the menu just above the console to narrow down the list on the right
3. Choose the only resource that the filter matches from the list on the right (`http://localhost/` here)
4. Click the Headers tab

Comment: sorry, there's no error return even with this code.it seems header was executed, but it does not forward.

Comment: @Melvin: Then you should debug by checking the HTTP headers received from the browser using suitable development tools (Chrome has this built in) or a debugging proxy like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). What headers is your page sending back?

Comment: view source in validate.php is blank. i am not sure how to check  HTTP headers via dev tools using chrome.

Comment: it returns Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:11407
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.100 Safari/534.30
Response Headers
Connection:Close
Content-type:text/html
Date:Sat, 25 Jun 2011 09:44:04 GMT
Server:Microsoft Expression Development Server/4.0.0.0
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.6

Comment: @Melvin: Well, you have to debug it... 1) Is there anything in the response? 2) Does your code get to run at all? 3) What if you try another header just to see what happens (e.g. `header("X-Testing: Hello world!")`)?

Comment: hi,I have checked the and found the problem. the problem was Microsoft Expression Development Server.. the same code when ported to apache server works flawlessly.

Answer (score 3):

The only way that i could do that was :

```
$url = "http://www.google.com";
echo "<script>window.open('".$url."','_self');</script>";
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me.  This way your debugger doesn't get confused and continues stepping into the referred `$url`

Answer (score 2):

You can also combine the two header calls into:

```
header('Location: http://localhost/MyBooks.php', true, 302);
exit;
```

So you won't need to remember the format/description of the HTTP Status code. The signature of the [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function is

> void **header** ( string $string [, bool
>   $replace = true [, int
>   $http_response_code ]] )

Answer (score 0):

I thought no problem in this code
check the execution come this line or not,

try without boolean

```
<?php header("Location: MyBooks.php); exit();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it was due to multiple locations being set in the header before the script ended.

```
<?php
    // WARNING: BAD CODE

    if($thisShouldBeTrue) {
        header('Location: http://www.example.com');
    }

    if($weShouldNeverGetHere) {
        header('Location: http://www.otherexample.com');
    }
?>
```

I thought that php would redirect immediately at the first header and never get to the second if block. I was wrong. Always die() or exit after a redirect if your intent is to go there immediately.

```
<?php
    // CORRECT

    if($thisMightBeTrue) {
        header('Location: http://www.example.com');
        die();
    }

    if($orThisMightBeTrue) {
        header('Location: http://www.otherexample.com');
        die();
    }
?>
```